# MySQL server has gone away on XAMPP

Tags: mysql, xampp

MySQL server has gone away is coming after I open site on localhost.
Following is the log file.

```
2022-02-17 11:28:12 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2022-02-17 11:28:12 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2022-02-17 11:28:12 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2022-02-17 11:28:12 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2022-02-17 11:28:12 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2022-02-17 11:28:12 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2022-02-17 11:28:12 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2022-02-17 11:28:12 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery from checkpoint LSN=588169799
2022-02-17 11:28:13 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2022-02-17 11:28:13 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
2022-02-17 11:28:13 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2022-02-17 11:28:13 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'E:\xampp2\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2022-02-17 11:28:13 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'E:\xampp2\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2022-02-17 11:28:13 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2022-02-17 11:28:13 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.20 started; log sequence number 588169808; transaction id 462509
2022-02-17 11:28:13 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from E:\xampp2\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2022-02-17 11:28:13 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2022-02-17 11:28:13 0 [Note] InnoDB: Cannot open 'E:\xampp2\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool' for reading: No such file or directory
2022-02-17 11:28:13 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
```

Comment: And what's your question about this? Did you try anything to resolve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Solved.
After trying for hours I am able to solve now. localhost site not opening, phpmyadmin was also not working.

What didn't work. I tried changing port from 3306 to 3307 in xampp config and php config file but this didn't help (after checking youtube, other similar questions). Changed back to port 3306.
Restarting system and xampp multiple times - no success.

Following steps I did which made it run again.

1. Made a backup/copy of data folder as data_v2
2. Created a blank data folder
3. Copied all files from mysql/backup folder to empty mysql/data folder (this step I did to check if the issue is with databases or files that were present in mysql/data folder before backup)
4. Checked phpmyadmin - it is now working
5. Copied required database folders from data_v2 folder to data folder
6. Checked phpmyadmin - it failed
7. Checked my.ini file present in mysql/data folder (not the one present in bin folder). Path here was wrong. It was default of c:/ (c drive), my xampp is in e:/ (e drive). Updated this path in my.ini.
8. Checked phpmyadmin - it is now working
9. I tried opening 1 of the databases in phpmyadmin. Then clicked on 1 of the tables. Issue - doesn't exist in engine
10. Copied file ibdata1 from data_v2 folder to data folder
11. Repeated Step 9. I tried opening 1 of the databases in phpmyadmin. Then clicked on 1 of the tables. It worked fine.
12. Tried opening a site on localhost. Issue - access denied for user
13. Created user in phpmyadmin. Repeated step 12. It worked.

Comment: Again faced this issue. Issue reason is: when windows update and system is autorestarted. User has not shutdown xampp.

Comment: In above steps, export templates were not present. Copied pma__export_templates.frm and pma__export_templates.ibd from data_v2>phpmyadmin to data>phpmyadmin folder